# Prevent scrolling when appending to or updating UITableView using NSFetchedResultsController with autolayout

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a chat application which backs a single-section UITableViewController with a core data Messages table.  Based on push messages, I update the status of a message or append new messages.  When a new message arrives, I'd like to scroll to the bottom of the table.  Each cell has variable height, which is driven by autolayout, using:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 76
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

1. I load the NSFetchRequest() in viewDidLoad, which loads the messages from a core data table, and jumps to the last message in viewDidAppear.  This works properly when running from Xcode, but if I start the app on an iPhone instead, it doesn't jump to the last message, but somewhere in the middle.  Also, if I defer the message to the main thread, it still doesn't work.  However, if I insert even a small delay like this, it always works properly:

   ```
   override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
     super.viewDidAppear(animated)

     // not sure why this delay is needed

     dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.001 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
       self.scrollToLastMessage()
     }
   }
   ```

   Of course I don't like having a fixed delay, especially one I don't understand.  Is there a specific event that I should hook for scrolling to the last message?
2. More vexing, I can't find a way to have my NSFetchResultsController .Insert (append) or .Update a row without the UITableViewController scrolling to another location.  I've tried capturing and restoring the contentOffset, which I have to do animated: false to prevent very screwed up animations, but the table still has visible scrolling flicker.  I've tried reloadData() for the whole table, reloadRowsAtIndexPaths() to just update the relevant cell, with and without beginUpdates() / endUpdates().  I also tried scrollToRowAtIndexPath(lastRow).  No matter what, I can't get this simple update to work without the UITableView autonomously scrolling.  It seems to scroll the changed row to the middle of the screen with animation, after which I have to scroll it back to where it should be.  Has anyone else noticed this?  Is this scrolling an artifact of NSFetchResultsController, a "feature" of UITableViewController or a result of using UITableViewAutomaticDimension?

   So far I get the best results with the following, but there is visible flicker.

   ```
   func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController!) {
     self.tableView.reloadData()
   }

   private func scrollToLastMessage() {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

       // without the check below, this oddly doesn't scroll to the right place (autolayout issue?)

       if self.tableView.contentSize.height > self.tableView.frame.size.height {
         let offset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.frame.size.height)
         self.tableView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. I notice when using UITableViewAutomaticDimension that the offset of the last row changes.  For instance, if I ask for the offset at one time, in order to jump to the right contentOffset to display it, the contentOffset can spontaneously change as UITableViewController probes other cells for their heights and scrolls around.  Is there a way to prevent this? I.e., to get UITableViewAutomaticDimension to always measure the real height of cells rather than the estimated height, so that I don't have to implement a rowHeight method?  As mentioned above, I've also tried scrollToRowAtIndexPath(lastRow), but that has the same weird, scrolling behaviour.